# Possible encrypted secure comminication to WebHDFS via HTTPS?

Tags: java, hadoop, https, hdfs, webhdfs

I'm using Cloudera Hadoop environment.

I've been familiar with WebHDFS over the past few days. I'm using it to perform various HDFS operations through REST API.

But, now i need to secure the communication to WebHDFS i.e using SSL/HTTPS.

Is this possible ? If yes, are there any defined steps to achieve this ?

**PS : Currently, I don't want to go for using Kerberos.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some properties you can set in hdfs-site.xml to enable HTTPS/SSL connections to the name node and data nodes:

- http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml

  - See the `dfs.https.enable` property
  - See the `dfs.https.server.keystore.resource` and `dfs.client.https.keystore.resource` properties for an ssl-server.xml (or client) file which defines the key and trustore paths / password etc (there are example ssl-server and ssl-client files in your conf folder)

You'll need to set a few properties in this file (and distribute it + your server cert / truststores to the NN and each DN in your cluster, and then restart HDFS).

There'a also some more detailed explanation available, here's some links that Google turned up:

- http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.5.0/bk_reference/content/ch_wire1.html

Note that Kerberos will not give you 'secure' communications (if by secure you mean encrypted), Kerberos just provides an authentication mechanism.

Comment: Thanks Chris for detailed answer. Can you please guide me for this problem ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20374419/hadoop-directory-with-spaces