# Hadoop Directory with Spaces

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, urlencode, filenotfoundexception

I'm running into a problem while providing Hadoop a directory that contains spaces.

e.g

```
inputDir = /abc/xyz/folder name/abc.txt
```

Hadoop somehow doesn't know about the "folder name" being the name of the folder with spaces between words.

I get the below error while doing that

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /abc/xyz/folder
```

Also, I tried providing with URL encoded.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /abc/xyz/folder%20name/abc.txt
```

But still throws me the same error.

Does anybody know the workaround for this ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Replace all spaces by + sign, this might be the solution.

Comment: Is this path being supplied in code, from the command line or somewhere else? Have you tried quotes around the entire path?

Comment: This is supplied from Oozie Client in Java. Using the set("path", "/abc/xyz/folder name/abc.txt");

Comment: I've hit this issue as well with calling the "hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal "/path/that/has spaces" hdfs://hostname:8020/dest/path
No form of escaping I could come up with would let me do this.

'path space', "path space", path\ space, "path\\ space", "path\\\\ space", &c

I'm of the opinion that this is an (? undocumented) limitation of hdfs tools

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Put file on HDFS with spaces in name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669210/put-file-on-hdfs-with-spaces-in-name)

Answer (score 2):

Replacing the space with %20 works for Hadoop shell. As in

```
sed 's/ /\%20/g'
```

And in the actual put command

```
hadoop fs -put "$inputDir" $putDest
```

Without the %20 you get a URI exception.  (Which gave me my clue to use %20 over an escape character \ .)

I realize you're doing via Java. The fact that you're getting a java.io.FileNotFoundException makes me wonder if the code is doing something else with inputDir as opposed  to being just the argument to the hadoop put, or an equivalent command of put.  If it does any kind of checking of inputDir outside of Hadoop commands it will fail. Java sees it as a path. Hadoop sees it as a URI.

Comment: Also wonder what type is inputDir and what types the arguments can be.

Answer (score 2):

**Hadoop does not support empty spaces** in input directory paths.

Replace **space** with **_** or your **preferred separator character** in your directory paths.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to some documentation stating this?
Furthermore: it might not support it, but it can be made to work

Answer (score 0):

Try setting using set("path", "/abc/xyz/folder\\ name/abc.txt");
Kindly, note the double back slash.

Comment: Why do you require space? can't you add _ instead of space in filename?

Answer (score 0):

```
inputDir = "/abc/xyz/folder name/"
```

must work

```
hadoop fs -ls "/abc/xyz/folder name/"
```

works fine